# congruences: number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have the following Diophantine equation on l, m, n(all belong to natural number)
$$(4a^2 - y^2)^l + (4ay)^m = (4a^2 + y^2)^n,$$ where a, y both belong to natural number with (a, y) = 1, 2a > 1, y is congruent to 3 (mod 4), whence l is even which is easily seen considering above equation (mod 4).

**my question is:**

> Show that, if a is odd, then m is congruent n (mod 2) and m is not equal to 1 iff n is even.

I have done it to some extent but could not get everything which is as follows:

From above equation we have $(4ay)^m$ is congruent $(2y^2)^n ( mod 4a^2 - y^2)$.

By the assumption on a, y
$$(4ay)^m/(4a^2 - y^2) = (-1)^m = (2y^2)^n/(4a^2 - y^2) = (-1)^n.$$ this is solved by Jacobi symbol properties. Hence m is congruent to n (mod 2).

Basically I want to ask

> How $(-1)^m = (-1)^n$ implies m is congruent to n (mod 2) comes?

Please elaborate it that would be helpful to me.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [your earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874779/number-theory-congruences).  Like that one, it is very hard to read.

Comment: Your terms look suspiciously similar to  Euclid's formula for generating pythagorean triples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple